# Haystack Elasticsearch filtering dates using lte it works as lt

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Using haystack + elasticsearch I found some problems with `lte` an dates.  It works as `lt`. I am having no problems with `gte`.

This is elasticsearch generated query:

```
"query": {"query_string": {"query": "(date_added:({* TO \"2017-01-25T00:00:00+01:00\"}) AND date_added:([\"2017-01-25T00:00:00+01:00\" TO *]))"
```

One option might be using `range` but not always I am using closed range, just one of the boundaries.

Comment: It's not clear what you problem is. Can you illustrate it with some examples?

Comment: In datetimefields filter `lte` works as `lt`

Comment: You need to show some example that backs up your claim. There's nothing in your question highlighting that.

Answer (score 0):

The query was not correctly built. I was mixing dates with `DateTimeField`. I had to complete `lte` field with `(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)` to propertly query elasticsearch